# Spacemacs config on OSX is not detected?

Tags: spacemacs

I have installed spacemacs following this tutorial:
https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#prerequisites

The spacemacs config is not detected.

The `$HOME` dir is set to `/home/<username>` and is correct.

Upon running `emacs --insecure` errors with "Unknown command insecure"
So I tried running emacs and manually setting the path to emacs.d dir like so:

`emacs --load ~/.emacs.d/init.el` and I got the following error:
`no such file or directory core-spacemacs`

I am pretty sure that I am missing something, since I am following the official tutorial, but I can't figure out what to do.

I think the config isn't loaded properly but since these are my first steps I am having a hard time debugging further.

Help appreciated!

PS:
OSX Catalina

```
emacs --version
GNU Emacs 28.0.50
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe I may have an idea why this is occurring. I had a similar problem earlier today where the command line in spacemacs was not finding my environment variables.

The reason this happened to me was that spacemacs uses zsh by default (not bash). I had environment variable for bash setup, but not for zsh.

To resolve this issue I created a .zshrc file in my home directory that held all my environment variables.

To see if this is the reason go to the command line within spacemacs. Type in a command line `echo $HOME`. If nothing is printed then you can conclude that it was caused by the environment variables not being found. Just create a .zshrc file (within your profile directory) with all of your environment variables.